# Simulate socket.io temporary disconnection in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, socket.io

I have a simple chat app written in javascript(client and node server) with socket.io. Users are permanently connected to server. I need to test how my application behaves when connection with node-socket.io-server being dropped. I need to block socket.io connection for a few seconds and then allow my app to connect again. I need to do it using the browser, without stopping the server.

I know that **chrome developer tools** has a future of simulating offline mode but this future does not drops/blocks socket.io connections.

So, how can i drop socket.io connection for a few seconds using chrome browser?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to simulate disconnection using **firewall** rules on either the backend or the client side.

On the client side you need to drop all outbound packets to the server, for a few seconds

Example using `iptables` (will work on linux clients):

```
SERVER_IP="1.1.1.1"

# Append rule
iptables -A OUTPUT -d $SERVER_IP -j DROP
sleep 5
# Delete rule
iptables -D OUTPUT -d $SERVER_IP -j DROP
```

On the server side you need to drop all inbound packets from_the specific client, for a few seconds

Example using `iptables` (will work on linux clients):

```
CLIENT_PUBLIC_IP="2.2.2.2"

# Append rule
iptables -A INPUT -s $CLIENT_PUBLIC_IP -j DROP
sleep 5
# Delete rule
iptables -D INPUT -s $CLIENT_PUBLIC_IP -j DROP
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this for a local connection?

Comment: Yes, you can block all incoming traffic on a specific port. See: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/iptables-block-port/

Comment: If you are using docker, see: https://serverfault.com/questions/704643/steps-for-limiting-outside-connections-to-docker-container-with-iptables

Docker also manipulates the iptables so it needs different handling